# How to access item values nested within the DOM?

Tags: javascript

I need to access a value within a form and an iframe from the parent form that is nested 3 and 4 levels deep.

Basically, the tree hierarchy (DOM) seems to be as follows:

```
<form name="formname" ....>
   <iframe id="refframe">
     <form name="formname" ...>              ==> Level 3
       <iframe id="iframe1">                 ==> Level 4
```

Now I have a item value at Level 3 (say myValue), that I would like to access from the top level (parent - Level 1)

With JavaScript, how could I access this item "myValue" from the parent top level?

The same goes with accessing an item at Level 4, within the iframe id of iframe1

Based on the above as I still am not sure how to access information but if I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="tabs0">
<iframe id="refframe" width="1210px" height="584px" frameborder="0" align="left"

overflow="auto" src="http://www.example.com" home="" name="Site1">
</iframe>

</div>

<div class="tabs1">
<iframe id="refframe" width="1210px" height="584px" frameborder="0" align="left" overflow="auto" src="http://www.def.com" name="Site2">
```

How can I access the src value within tabs1 class iframe from the parent window, i.e.

```
src="http://www.def.com"
```

Comment: Please clarify whether or not you are dealing with external domains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the content in the iframe loaded from the same domain as the parent document?  If not, then due to browser security restrictions ([same domain policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)), you won't be able to access it via javascript.

If it is from the same domain, you should be able to use `getElementById` without any problems.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `id` as a unique value (as it should be -- see e.g. [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html), section 7.5.2) -- then, [GetElementById](http://www.w3schools.com/HTMLDOM/met_doc_getelementbyid.asp) does just what you want, without requiring you to navigate any complex hierarchies.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form name="formname" .... id="form-first">
    <iframe id="one" src="iframe2.html">
    </iframe>
</form>


function iframeRef( frameRef ) {
    return frameRef.contentWindow ? frameRef.contentWindow.document : frameRef.contentDocument
}

var inside = iframeRef( document.getElementById('one') )

var secondIframe = inside.getElementsByTagName('iframe')
alert( secondIframe.id ) // make sure theres an iframe with an id in the iframe2.html.
```

You can use iframeRef to grab the reference inside of the iframe, and just do keep doing that to get to child iframes. This should work for IE.

Comment: Note: This will *only* work if the documents in the iframe are on YOUR domain.

Comment: RE: Your update - you *cannot* access the iframe contents if it's not in your domain.

Comment: Understand what you are saying but I am actually working within an intranet type set-up where I actually have access to all sites that I reference even though I am jumping to different sites within an iframe. Based on this, can I still not access contents?

Comment: My answer was posted 3 hours ago. Have you actually tried it? Did it not work? If so and if you got any sort of denied/restricted error then it won't work without relying on something like JSONP

Comment: Tried your solution and all I am getting at the moment is the messgae "undefined" - any ideas?